# Partially freeze a layer in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was looking for a way to partially freeze a layer in a Keras model. If I were to freeze a layer, I would just set the `trainable` property to `False` like this:

```
model.get_layer('myLayer').trainable = False
```

But, let's take for example a Dense layer with `n` nodes. Is there a way to set to non-trainable the first `i` nodes, leaving trainable the remaining `n-i`?

I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation. The only solution I can think of is to:

1. Save the weights of the layer `x` that I wanted to partially freeze,
2. Train the model leaving the `x` layer trainable,
3. After train re-load the weights for the nodes that I didn't wanted to train in the first place.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Also I'm not sure if this strategy is entirely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `model.layers[ ]` to get the layers from the trained model to make them non-trainable.
For example,

```
model=tf.keras.Sequential([
                   tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')])
```

After training this model, to make the first six layers non-trainable, make them sequential and build the model by providing the input_shape.

```
model1=model.layers[:6]
model1=tf.keras.Sequential(model1)
model1.build((None,28,28,1)) 

#Setting trainable = False will make them non-trainable.
model1.trainable = False
```

Now, you can add layers to the model you want to train.

```
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransairamineni/7b6e1547d2e6a12f9bd3bbc140ca1e50). Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is not quite what I wanted to achieve. From what I understand with this code you are freezing whole layers, but I wanted to know if it was possible to only freeze a portion of nodes of a particular layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with, even though is a bit different from what I asked for, but maybe can be useful to someone.

What I wanted to achieve was to create a model that I could train incrementally with a task-incremental learning technique. Not having experience with this type of methods my first idea was to:

- Train "normally" the first N classes, having a last Dense layer with N nodes.
- Add additional N classes, replacing the last Dense layer with a new one of 2N nodes and copying the previously trained classes weights of the old layer to the new one.

Having to train the new classes incrementally, I had the necessity of freezing the first N nodes of the last layer, while training the new N nodes: so partially freezing a single layer.

However I realized that adding nodes to an existing last layer was not the right methodology (at least for task-incremental learning).
I solved it by adding a new head to the model for each new set of classes. So multiple last layers. This way was pretty straightforward to freeze the old heads, which are proper independent layers, while training the new one.

This was the solution that worked for what I wanted to achieve, however it does not really answer to the question "how to partially freeze a single layer", so I won't accept this as answer.